# whm password is invalid

Tags: passwords, cpanel, root

I installed [whm](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cpanel-whm-centos-7/) on centos7  to run cpanel on my server. After the installation finished, I cant login to whm , when I [google](https://www.superb.net/kb/index.php/control-panels/30-cpanelwhm/158-what-is-my-default-login-for-whm) it, I found the password by default is my root password for server but even with that i can't login.
Does anyone know what happened and what I should do?

Comment: Login via ssh as root and do a passwd root to change the password then try again

Comment: thanks dude my problem solved .

Comment: Great. Don't forget to vote for the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login via ssh as root and do a passwd root to change the password then try again